# Updating a page automatically in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a simple app in Ionic that has a main page with a last viewed section and a favourites page. When i view an item it is added to the last viewed list but it wont be displayed on the page until it is reloaded, the same happens with the favourites button, is there any way around this?

This is the function i am using to create the last view list, it passes in the id of the item and adds it to the local storage. The second function is used in the ng-repeat filter to display the item that was viewed.

```
$scope.lastview = function(id) {
//checks if the id being passed in is already in the array
//if it isn't it will add it to the beginning array then stringify it
var c = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['last']);
  if (last.indexOf(id) == -1){
    if (c.length > 3){
      last.pop();
      }
    last.unshift(id);
    $window.localStorage['last'] = JSON.stringify(last);
    }
}

var f = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['last']);

// this one is used for last viewed offices
$scope.ifinfav2 = function(office){
  return f.indexOf(office.id) !== -1;
};
```

Main view where last viewed is.

```
<ion-view view-title="Main Page">
<!-- Favourites button -->
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button icon ion-android-star" ui-sref="Favourites">
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

    <ion-content>
    <!-- Search function starts here -->
        <label class="item item-input">
            <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="search" id="search-criteria" placeholder="City, Country or Office Name" ng-model="query[queryBy]">
        </label>
        <!-- Search function ends here -->
        <!-- Main content starts here -->
        <!-- ng-show hides the list of offices and displays them when the user starts searching  -->
        <ion-list ng-show="query[queryBy]">
        <!-- Creates each item through collection-repeat and is filtered by the query linked to the search field -->
        <!-- ng-click opens the modal that will have the enlarged office address and the map of the office -->
            <ion-item class="item-text-wrap item-icon-right" id="output" collection-repeat="office in offices|filter:query" ng-controller="ModalCtrl" ng-click="openModal(); lastview(office.id);">
                <!-- Outputs all the data from offices.json -->
                <h3 id="LocName">{{office.LocationName}}</h3>
                <p id="details">{{office.LocAddressLine1 + ", " + office.LocAddressLine2 + ", " + office.LocCity + ", " + office.LocCountryDescription + ", " + office.LocZipPostalCode}}</p>

                <!-- Creates the favourite icon on each list item, when the star is clicked the togglefav function is run -->
                <i ng-class="{'icon ion-android-star': favicon(office.id), 'icon ion-android-star-outline': !favicon(office.id)}" ng-click="togglefav(office.id); $event.stopPropagation();"></i>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-content>

        <!-- Last view offices list, currently only updates on app refresh -->
        <div id="cont" ng-hide="query[queryBy]">
                <h3 class="title" id="text">Last Viewed</h3>
            <!-- the filter with this collection repeat runs the function ifinfav2 which only displays items in the localstorage -->
                <ion-item id="fav" class="item-icon-right" ng-repeat="office in offices|filter:ifinfav2" ng-controller="ModalCtrl" ng-click="openModal(office.id);">
                <h3>{{office.LocationName}}</h3>
                <p id="details">{{office.LocAddressLine1 + ", " + office.LocAddressLine2 + ", " + office.LocCity + ", " + office.LocCountryDescription + ", " + office.LocZipPostalCode}}</p>
                <i ng-class="{'icon ion-android-star': favicon(office.id), 'icon ion-android-star-outline': !favicon(office.id)}" ng-click="togglefav(office.id); $event.stopPropagation();"></i>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </div>

</ion-view>
```

Comment: please add your view to your post

Comment: are you sure that angular will know to watch the filter for changes?  Does it auto-refresh if you set the filtered data as a $scope variable instead of using the filter on the ng-repeat?

Comment: using $scope doesn't work, i am using a function on the filter not a variable